# Having trouble with basic program "inappropriate argument value (of correct type)"

Tags: python, jes

sorry if this is worded poorly, it's my first post.
I'm having difficulties with a code im making for class. It needs to crop an image chosen by the user. But every time I run the code I get the result of:
Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
here's the code:

```
def crop(startX,endX,startY,endY):

file = pickAFile()
pic  = makePicture(file)
show(pic)

newPic    = makeEmptyPicture(endX - startX, endY - startY)
newPixels = getPixels(newPic)

for x in range(startX,endX):
 for y in range(startY,endY):

   color = getColor(getPixel(pic, x, y))

   setColor(newPixels,color)
```

When I use the code, it gives me an error to line 44.
If i could have help solving this problem I'd greatly appreciate it.
Thank you!

Here's the full problem:
Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.
Please check line 42 of /Users/robertking/homework_4a

Comment: Error on line 44...I don't see 44 lines here. Copy and paste the stack trace so that we can see the full error message.

Comment: Also, please fix your indention.

Comment: I just realized i forgot i had another function on the project, so the lines arent correct. hold on. it's line 18... Here's the entire message.

Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.
Please check line 42 of /Users/robertking/homework_4a

Comment: I don't know JES, but it looks like `newPixels` is a list of pixels, and you're passing that whole list to `setColor`, but the first argument of `setColor` needs to be a _single_ pixel.